# Is this how I can select all employees with two WHERE conditions?

Tags: mysql, relational-database

> Employee (EmployeeNo, EmployeeName, EmployeeAddress, RegionCode, EmployeeType)
>
> List the Employee numbers, names and address of all the employees working in the Region whose code is MUN and the name is John Smith.

The code I have used is below I would like to know is it correct?

```
SELECT e.EmployeeNo,  e.EmployeeName, e.EmployeeAddress
FROM Employee e
WHERE e.RegionCode =(MUN) AND e.Employee = (John Smith)
ORDER BY e.EmployeeNumber;
```

Comment: It *seems* correct (but for the curly quotes instead of single quotes). Did you try it ?

Comment: No it is a exam question and I have not created a DB to try it on it is a hand written test.

Comment: Then, create it ? There's online tools to test SQL. Try [db fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/). What result did you get for this question ?